# Working with Cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-android

I am new to cocos2d and never used it before.

I found a cocos2dx project online and I would like to use it. So my question is, how do i import an existing cocos2d project or how do I build an `apk` using cocos2d project files.

Another question is can the building be done on cocos2d, if so then how?

Comment: I ca'n get the your last question. Cocos2d is nothing but a bunch of files, so-called Game Engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Cocos2d` family (like `Cocos2dx` and `cocos2d-iphone`) is actually just Game Engine. So you need an IDE (like `Visual Studio`) to develop your game.

First download the engine itself from [here](http://cocos2d-x.org/).
After downloading and unzipping, you need to follow [this page](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_Start_A_New_Cocos2D-X_Game) in order to create a new empty project.

At this point you will have a folder including `cocos2dx` engine and a simple *Hello World* project.

Now if you want to run the project and continue your development on your PC/Mac, you can easily go to `proj.win32` or `proj.macos` folder and run the *Visual Studio* or *XCode* project. From there you can build a `.exe` (Win) or `.ipa` (iOS).

If you want to build a `.apk` for your Android device you can follow the [this page](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_run_cpp-tests_on_Android) showing you how to build project for Android.